# Some Chinese, Japanese characters appear garbled on IE/FF

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, multilingual, cjk

We have a content rendering site that displays content in multiple languages. The site is built using JSP and content fetched from Oracle DB. All our pages are UTF-8 compliant.

When displaying zh/jp content, out of the complete content, only some of the character appear garbled (square boxes on IE and diamond question marks on FF). The data in DB does not have any garbled character. Since we dont understand the language, we dont know what characters are problematic. Would appreciate some pointers to the solution please. Could it be that some characters may be appearing invalid to the browsers?

Example in FF:
ネット犯���者 がアプ

脆弱性保護機能 - ネット犯���者 がアプリケーションのセキュリティホール (脆弱性) を突いて、パソコンに脅威を侵入させることを阻止します。

Answer (score 0):

In doubt on the sanity of a UTF-8 encoding, you can always re-encode it either with a good text editor or with a specialized tool like iconv :

```
 iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 yourfile > youfile2
```

If your file is indeed invalid, iconv will also give you some information on the problem.

But, another way you might want to explore is installing new fonts for Far East languages…

Indeed, not knowing the actual bytes used in your file, it is hard to say why their are replaced with a replacement character � (U+FFFD). Thus, you might want to post a hex dump of the parts of your file that do not work.